# Splashscreen that loads per visit

Tags: php, javascript, html, splash-screen

I have built a webpage, `splashcreen.html`, that when someone loads `index.php` will automatically go to. But I wish to also have a button, return to index.php, that allows users to go back to the homepage. But if the person closes the browser, this entire process restarts.

So it goes:

1. Open browser, `index.php`
2. Redirect to `splashcreen.html`
3. user clicks button, return to `index.php`
4. navigate without redirect
5. User closes browser
6. reopen and start this whole process again.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not replace index.php with splashscreen.html?

Comment: I don't want to build a separate navigation with a new splashscreen, there is little content on the splashscreen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your `index.php` as the splash screen. Then the user clicks the button, redirect to `home.php` which is the "real" homepage.

Then instead of Home links pointing to the root (which implies `index.php`, therefore splash screen), have them point to `home.php` instead.

So:

1. user opens `yoursite.com` and meets your splash screen
2. user clicks button to go to `home.php`
3. user navigates normally
4. once user closes and reopens browser to visit `yoursite.com`, well.. splash screen again!

If later on you get tired of the splash screen and plan not to use it anymore, you can use a simple .htaccess rule to redirect index.php requests to home.php

Comment: Joseph, this sounds like a solid idea.
So, initially can I use .htaccess to redirect to splashscreen.html? And then I just have a button to return to index.php (which now the internet doesn't read as the loading page?)

Comment: Okay, I tried this, but then it does not load all of my images when I change the DirectoryIndex in the .htaccess. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JonathanSafa are you using a CMS? what did you put into .htaccess?

Comment: No I am not sure what CMS is... I put into one line 

DirectoryIndex /newbook/html (which is the splash page)

It is now showing up with a list of the parent directory files.

Comment: @JonathanSafa requests to index will never arrive to index if you use the htaccess to redirect to splash.

Answer (score 2):

Save a cookie, or send a GET value:

`<a href="index.php?spash=0">Go Home!</a>`.

Comment: the cookie would be better, so you don't have to go back to splash every time you go to the website

Comment: Exactly, but maybe the OP wants that? I am just giving him some options that he may not have heard of.

Comment: Look at his 6th bullet. I think he really wants it ;)

Comment: Is that    ?spash    supposed to be    ?splash

Comment: Hidde, I am not sure what you mean by send a GET value. I am new to all of this, what exactly should I do?

Comment: You can use a GET value using the `$_GET` variable. The content comes from the URL, so if you call `<a href="index.php?splash=0">Go Home!</a>`, you can use `$_GET['splash']` to get the value of splash (in this case 0). You can use that value to determine if you need the slash screen or not. Read some documentation first, they usually answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just set a cookie with JavaScript when the button is clicked in `splashscreen.html`, and have the php (or JS, whatever's redirecting) on `index.php` not rediect if the cookie is set.  This is pretty easy, just search for it on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You dont actually need to redirect to splash.html you could just use a session to store if its been seen or just continue to do your index.php

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['splash'])){
    //Show splash screen
    ob_start();
    include('./splash.html');
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo $contents;
    $_SESSION['splash']=true;
    die;
}

//Do normal index.php
?>
```